# html form vertically split - submission issues

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submission

i have created a 2 pager website. It is basically a data gathering site.

On first page, i gather some information, in a form. I pass this to the second page using the "GET" method of the form submission.

On the second page, I parse the information and display it in `readonly` format. Alongside this information, there is another text field, which user is supposed to fill in.

the UI looks perfect, but the functionality is somehow broken.

Have a look at the code. I gotta paste more code here, as i do not know which part is responsible for functionality. It could be `javascript` functions, so including those. I have to include the `css`, as it is responsible for vertical splits, and bug might reside there and obviously `html` as well, as there might  be few structural issues. Hence, this is the minimalistic code that can be there for the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">

<script>

                var part1;
                var part2;
                var part3;
                function GetSimpleStory(){
                    document.getElementById("emotion").value  = getParameterByName("emotion");
                    var part1 = getParameterByName("myInputs_1[]");
                    addInput("previousInput_1", "Input_1", "prevInputs_1", "input_1", part1);
                    var part2 = getParameterByName("myInputs_2[]");
                    addInput("previousInput_2", "Input_2", "prevInputs_2", "input_2", part2);
                    var part3 = getParameterByName("myInputs_3[]");
                    addInput("previousInput_3", "Input_3", "prevInputs_3", "input_3", part3);
                }


                function getParameterByName(name){
                    var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
                    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)", 'g');
                    var match, result = [];
                    while ((match = regex.exec(url)) !== null)
                        result.push(match[1]);
                    return result;
                }

                function addInput(divName, nextDiv, arrName, nextArray, contents){
                    contents.forEach(function (value, i){
                        value = value.replace(new RegExp('\\+', 'g'), ' ');
                        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                        newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + arrName + "[]' value='" + value + "' readonly>";
                        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

                        var newdiv1 = document.createElement('div');
                        newdiv1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + nextArray + "[]' value='' required>";
                        document.getElementById(nextDiv).appendChild(newdiv1);
                    })
                }


</script>

<style>
html *
{
    color: #000 !important;
    font-family: Arial !important;
}

.wrapper
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow:auto;
}

.window
{
    width: 120%;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    float: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.generatedEmotion
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #f9f99f;
    font-size:2.4em;
}

 .generatedEmotionHidden
 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:2.4em;
    visibility: hidden;
 }

input[type=text], select {
    width: 150%;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin: 4px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 0.5cm;
}

.floating-box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 0.5cm;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="GetSimpleStory()">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="window">
        <div class="windowContent">

            <p id="demo"></p>

            <form method="POST" action="http://formspree.io/sga267@uky.edu" align="center">
                <b>Emotion </b><br>
                <input type="text" value="" id="emotion" class="generatedEmotion" readonly>
                <div id="previousInput_1">
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly class="floating-box">
John arrived at Sally's house to pick her up. John and Sally were going to a fancy restaurant that evening for a dinner. John was little nervous because he was going to ask Sally to marry him.</textarea>
                 </div>
                <div id="previousInput_2">
                        <div class="floating-box">Waiter shows John and Sally to their table.</div>
                </div>
                <div id="previousInput_3">
                        <div class="floating-box">John asks Sally, "Will you marry me?"</div>
                 </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="window">
        <div class="windowContent">

                            <br><br>    <b>Interesting Version</b><br><br><br><br><br>
            <div id="Input_1">
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50"  class="floating-box">




                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="Input_2">
                <textarea rows="2" cols="50"  class="floating-box">

                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="Input_3">
                <textarea rows="1" cols="50"  class="floating-box">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Both parts completed, Submit story">

        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
    <div class="window">
        <div class="windowContent">
            <p><font size="6"><b>some other text goes in this vertical div</b></font></p>

            </font>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Problems:

1. After submitting form, first field, `emotion` is not submitted. I read on SO that if it is `readonly`, it should be submitted.
2. Entire second vertical div is not getting submitted. It is made up of arrays `input_1`, `input_2` and `input_3`. I have no idea what is wrong, because the similarly "stuffed" `prevInputs` get submitted

FYI, I am submitting the information via `formspree.io`

PS: url to try->

```
soq.html?emotion=Surprise&myInputs_1%5B%5D=hello&myInputs_1%5B%5D=dear+reader&myInputs_2%5B%5D=thank+you+for&myInputs_2%5B%5D=reading+the+question&myInputs_3%5B%5D=and+trying+to+solve+the+probelm
```

Comment: your HTML is not valid ... the browser does it's best to fix the issue, but you'll find, using element inspector in browser developer tools will show that half the form elements are outside the form tag - step one to fix: fix your HTML

Comment: @JaromandaX gotcha! that quickly fixes the problem_2, the arrays are getting submitted for the second vertical div. but the read_only element is still not getting submitted. Possible to give further pointers?

Comment: perhaps you need to give that element a `name` attribute

Comment: @JaromandaX both problems are now solved. Thank you. Please write an answer, I would be glad to accept it.